# How to use user defined function in mustache php

Tags: php, mustache, mustache.php

I have set up `mustache php` in my project.

```
echo $template->render(array(
     'data'=>$data, 
     'lang'=>$lang,
     'getMaritialStatus' => function($text, Mustache_LambdaHelper $helper) {
       return Common::getTextInHindi(ucwords(strtolower($helper->render($text))));
      }
));
```

and my user defined function is

```
public static function getTextInHindi($maritialStatus) {
      return $GLOBALS['lang'][$maritialStatus];
}
```

Now in my user defined function as you can see above when I try to print

```
print_r($GLOBALS['lang']['Married']);  //gives correct output
print_r($GLOBALS['lang'][$maritialStatus]); //gives undefined index error
```

even though `$maritialStatus` contains the string `'Married'`.

Why is this happening

Comment: is it possible that the case is not right, so that the value of the variable `$martialStatus` is `married`? In that case perhaps you'd to write `$GLOBALS['lang'][ucfirst($maritialStatus)]` or `$GLOBALS['lang'][ucfirst(strtolower($maritialStatus))]`

Comment: Another option is that you have to trim the value: `$GLOBALS['lang'][trim($maritialStatus)]`

Comment: trim did the job thanks......silly mistakes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out the value had to be trimmed:

```
 $GLOBALS['lang'][trim($maritialStatus)]
```

At best trimming is already done before, so that it exists in the right format already:

```
echo $template->render(array(
     'data'=>$data, 
     'lang'=>$lang,
     'getMaritialStatus' => function($text, Mustache_LambdaHelper $helper) {
       return trim(Common::getTextInHindi(ucwords(strtolower($helper->render($text)))));
      }
));
```

Comment: one more thing you can help me here....I am passing $lang to my mustache template which is also my $GLOBALS['lang'] array...so instead of calling the function is there any I can use $lang here.

Comment: As you alter the value in your function (`ucwords(strtolower($helper->render($text))`) I don't see how, but perhaps if you debug `$Globals['lang']` the desired value exists already in the right format.